# How do I find out what caused a taint on one of my k8s nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

We have a k8s cluster with approx 8 nodes. Sometimes a node is tainted and we dont know why. Yesterday I found a taint on one of my nodes:

```
taints:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      effect: NoSchedule
      timeAdded: '2023-11-22T23:13:15Z'
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      effect: NoExecute
      timeAdded: '2023-11-22T23:13:17Z'
```

How can I find out what caused this taint? I have tried looking at prometheus metrics and journalctl but I can't find anyting that helps me understand what caused this.

Comment: is it self managed or runs on one of the cloud providers?

Comment: It is self managed, microk8s.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the cause of a taint on a kubernetes nodes you can follow below steps:

1.Get a list of all nodes in your cluster by running the following command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

2.Inspect a node by running the following command

```
kubectl describe node NODE_NAME
```

3.In the returned output, look for the Taints field.

As mentioned in the official kubernetes [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/) :

The node controller automatically taints a Node when certain conditions are true. The following taints are built in:

- `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready`: Node is not ready. This corresponds to the NodeCondition Ready being "False".

In case a node is to be drained, the node controller or the kubelet adds relevant taints with NoExecute effect. This effect is added by default for the `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready` and `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable taints`. If the fault condition returns to normal, the kubelet or node controller can remove the relevant taint(s).

You can also refer to this link on [Control Scheduling with node taints](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints)  for more information.